# How can I determine validation loss for faster RCNN (PyTorch)?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, object-detection

I followed this tutorial for object detection:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html

and their GitHub repository that contains the following `train_one_epoch` and `evaluate` functions:

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/references/detection/engine.py

However, I want to calculate losses during validation. I  implemented this for the evaluation loss, where essentially to obtain losses, `model.train()` needs to be on:

```
@torch.no_grad()
def evaluate_loss(model, data_loader, device):
    val_loss = 0
    model.train()
    for images, targets in data_loader:
        images = list(image.to(device) for image in images)
        targets = [{k: v.to(device) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]

        loss_dict = model(images, targets)

        losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())

        # reduce losses over all GPUs for logging purposes
        loss_dict_reduced = utils.reduce_dict(loss_dict)
        losses_reduced = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict_reduced.values())
        val_loss += losses_reduced
  
  validation_loss = val_loss/ len(data_loader)    
  return validation_loss
```

I then place it after the learning rate scheduler step in my for loop:

```
 for epoch in range(args.num_epochs):
        # train for one epoch, printing every 10 iterations
        train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, train_data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
    
        # update the learning rate
        lr_scheduler.step()

        validation_loss = evaluate_loss(model, valid_data_loader, device=device)

        # evaluate on the test dataset
        evaluate(model, valid_data_loader, device=device)
```

Does this look correct or can it interfere with training or produce inaccurate validation losses?

If ok, by using this, is there is a simple way in applying early stopping for validation loss?

I'm considering just adding something like this after the evaluate model function shown above:

```
torch.save({
            'epoch': epoch,
            'model_state_dict': net.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'validation loss': valid_loss,
            }, PATH)
```

where I also aim to save the model at every epoch for checkpointing purposes. However I need to determine the validation "loss" for saving the "best" model.

Comment: You can have `model.train` on only if there is no batch norm or dropout, otherwise these will be updated/on (respectively) during evaluation.

Comment: You could create your own forward function for evaluation by copying [the pytorch function](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/f40c8df02c197d1a9e194210e40dee0e6a6cb1c3/torchvision/models/detection/generalized_rcnn.py#L46). You'll see in that link you just need to change line 110 to return detections and losses.

Comment: I looked into the PyTorch function you provided and it's already returning detections and losses. I don't think I fully understand what you mean. I'm sure you have the correct answer...would you be able to elaborate further as a posted answer below? It's something I'm struggling to get my head around and it appears it's a common issue with torch visions RCNN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it turns out no stages of the pytorch fasterrcnn return losses when `model.eval()` is set. However, you can just manually use the `forward` code to generate the losses in evaluation mode:

```
from typing import Tuple, List, Dict, Optional
import torch
from torch import Tensor
from collections import OrderedDict
from torchvision.models.detection.roi_heads import fastrcnn_loss
from torchvision.models.detection.rpn import concat_box_prediction_layers
def eval_forward(model, images, targets):
    # type: (List[Tensor], Optional[List[Dict[str, Tensor]]]) -> Tuple[Dict[str, Tensor], List[Dict[str, Tensor]]]
    """
    Args:
        images (list[Tensor]): images to be processed
        targets (list[Dict[str, Tensor]]): ground-truth boxes present in the image (optional)
    Returns:
        result (list[BoxList] or dict[Tensor]): the output from the model.
            It returns list[BoxList] contains additional fields
            like `scores`, `labels` and `mask` (for Mask R-CNN models).
    """
    model.eval()

    original_image_sizes: List[Tuple[int, int]] = []
    for img in images:
        val = img.shape[-2:]
        assert len(val) == 2
        original_image_sizes.append((val[0], val[1]))

    images, targets = model.transform(images, targets)

    # Check for degenerate boxes
    # TODO: Move this to a function
    if targets is not None:
        for target_idx, target in enumerate(targets):
            boxes = target["boxes"]
            degenerate_boxes = boxes[:, 2:] <= boxes[:, :2]
            if degenerate_boxes.any():
                # print the first degenerate box
                bb_idx = torch.where(degenerate_boxes.any(dim=1))[0][0]
                degen_bb: List[float] = boxes[bb_idx].tolist()
                raise ValueError(
                    "All bounding boxes should have positive height and width."
                    f" Found invalid box {degen_bb} for target at index {target_idx}."
                )

    features = model.backbone(images.tensors)
    if isinstance(features, torch.Tensor):
        features = OrderedDict([("0", features)])
    model.rpn.training=True
    #model.roi_heads.training=True


    #####proposals, proposal_losses = model.rpn(images, features, targets)
    features_rpn = list(features.values())
    objectness, pred_bbox_deltas = model.rpn.head(features_rpn)
    anchors = model.rpn.anchor_generator(images, features_rpn)

    num_images = len(anchors)
    num_anchors_per_level_shape_tensors = [o[0].shape for o in objectness]
    num_anchors_per_level = [s[0] * s[1] * s[2] for s in num_anchors_per_level_shape_tensors]
    objectness, pred_bbox_deltas = concat_box_prediction_layers(objectness, pred_bbox_deltas)
    # apply pred_bbox_deltas to anchors to obtain the decoded proposals
    # note that we detach the deltas because Faster R-CNN do not backprop through
    # the proposals
    proposals = model.rpn.box_coder.decode(pred_bbox_deltas.detach(), anchors)
    proposals = proposals.view(num_images, -1, 4)
    proposals, scores = model.rpn.filter_proposals(proposals, objectness, images.image_sizes, num_anchors_per_level)

    proposal_losses = {}
    assert targets is not None
    labels, matched_gt_boxes = model.rpn.assign_targets_to_anchors(anchors, targets)
    regression_targets = model.rpn.box_coder.encode(matched_gt_boxes, anchors)
    loss_objectness, loss_rpn_box_reg = model.rpn.compute_loss(
        objectness, pred_bbox_deltas, labels, regression_targets
    )
    proposal_losses = {
        "loss_objectness": loss_objectness,
        "loss_rpn_box_reg": loss_rpn_box_reg,
    }

    #####detections, detector_losses = model.roi_heads(features, proposals, images.image_sizes, targets)
    image_shapes = images.image_sizes
    proposals, matched_idxs, labels, regression_targets = model.roi_heads.select_training_samples(proposals, targets)
    box_features = model.roi_heads.box_roi_pool(features, proposals, image_shapes)
    box_features = model.roi_heads.box_head(box_features)
    class_logits, box_regression = model.roi_heads.box_predictor(box_features)

    result: List[Dict[str, torch.Tensor]] = []
    detector_losses = {}
    loss_classifier, loss_box_reg = fastrcnn_loss(class_logits, box_regression, labels, regression_targets)
    detector_losses = {"loss_classifier": loss_classifier, "loss_box_reg": loss_box_reg}
    boxes, scores, labels = model.roi_heads.postprocess_detections(class_logits, box_regression, proposals, image_shapes)
    num_images = len(boxes)
    for i in range(num_images):
        result.append(
            {
                "boxes": boxes[i],
                "labels": labels[i],
                "scores": scores[i],
            }
        )
    detections = result
    detections = model.transform.postprocess(detections, images.image_sizes, original_image_sizes)  # type: ignore[operator]
    model.rpn.training=False
    model.roi_heads.training=False
    losses = {}
    losses.update(detector_losses)
    losses.update(proposal_losses)
    return losses, detections
```

Testing this code gives me:

```
import torchvision
from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FastRCNNPredictor

# load a model pre-trained on COCO
model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)

# replace the classifier with a new one, that has
# num_classes which is user-defined
num_classes = 2  # 1 class (person) + background
# get number of input features for the classifier
in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
# replace the pre-trained head with a new one
model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)
losses, detections = eval_forward(model,torch.randn([1,3,300,300]),[{'boxes':torch.tensor([[100,100,200,200]]),'labels':torch.tensor([0])}])

{'loss_classifier': tensor(0.6594, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward0>),
'loss_box_reg': tensor(0., grad_fn=<DivBackward0>),
 'loss_objectness': tensor(0.5108, grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyWithLogitsBackward0>),
 'loss_rpn_box_reg': tensor(0.0160, grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)}
```

Comment: I've got back round to looking at this. I presume I would need to copy all files from the torchvision model repo.  Someone on the PyTorch form suggested keeping the parent module in a training state and only applying ```.eval()``` on dropout and batchnorm layers. Although, I'm not really sure how to apply this.

Comment: I gave you a function you can use...

Comment: I just realised although I import mask_rcnn, I think the code uses generalized_rcnn, I'm guessing I should download the repo and call the amended script from a local repo rather than directly from torchvision!

Comment: So the function above is modified from `generalized_rcnn`. Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm sure this is a simple solution, I just don't know where I should be adding the forward function based on the above code provided. I imagine I would be calling it after ```train_one_epoch```...

Comment: so the code i've written... you can copy it into your local directory/script. You don't need to modify any of the torch code because i've done it for you

Comment: ah ok cool! well the only question I really have is would I need to fir this into the above evaluation function that is in the engine.py script? I ask because it expects images and targets as input and for that function I just feed in the dataloader

Comment: no because I've included the model as an input to the function, so you'll need to iterate over your dataloader and feed each batch sequentially, whilst incrementing your loss accumulating variable.

Comment: hey @jhso, I just wanted to make sure this I have the right interpretation, I see you didn't comment out ```model.rpn.training=True``` near the beginning of the code. Is this to ensure object proposals are being generated despite being in ```.eval()```?

Comment: Well... it's been a while but if I recall correctly, what you've said is correct. You'll need to make sure you zero out any grads that might accumulate in this time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  know it's been a long time! Ok, well I see ```model.eval()``` is inside the ```eval_forward``` function. If you look at the last answer at the bottom, you can see for the ```evaluate_loss``` function, I put  ``` with torch.no_grad():``` , I'm assuming this is ok and should stop gradients accumulating (and that its ok to be placed before ```model.eval()``` which is inside the ```eval_forward``` function you kindly defined).

Comment: @jhso Do you have a explanation why the mAP and other metrics are different, when I use the detections of your eval method in comparison when I just use mode(imgs) ?

Comment: @Perry45 do not compare this to `model(imgs)` as this code should be solely used to generate the loss of the model on a test/validation set. Predictions generated using this method will have foreground/background sampling and other train-time augmentations to generate the loss.

Comment: @jhso Yeah, I tried also another approach by tweaking the lib files directly and I recognized there that it is because of roi_heads.py: if self.training: proposals, matched_idxs, labels, regression_targets = self.select_training_samples(proposals, targets) So I need this for the losses but then the proposals and mAP change. So your eval method is useless for me because I want to use it with my validation step in each epoch and I need the correct validation mAP... So there is no way to get the losses and the correct val mAP?

Comment: Sure I could use your method AND model(imgs), to get the losses and the correct mAP but this would hurt performance, but maybe I will check it and give it a try....

Comment: why would it hurt performance?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for your patience. I've posted below a snippet of code that iterates over the dataloader. I think I've understood you but from what I've done below I get an empty dictionary when I print out the losses:

```
@torch.no_grad()
def evaluate_loss(model, data_loader, device):
    val_loss = 0
    for images, targets in data_loader:
        images = list(image.to(device) for image in images)
        targets = [{k: v.to(device) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]

        #USE PROVIDED CODE to get losses and detections
        losses, detections = eval_forward(model, images, targets)

        print(losses) # empty {}

         val_loss += sum(loss for loss in losses.values())

    validation_loss = val_loss/ len(data_loader)    
    return validation_loss
```

When I print losses and detections I get this:

```
{} [{'boxes': tensor([[  0.0000, 430.0531, 364.2619, 512.0000],
        [  6.8726, 455.9226, 256.0113, 509.0516],
        [  5.7750, 227.0236, 138.1525, 503.0216],
        [  0.0000, 275.2110,  87.6766, 512.0000],
        [ 55.3590, 484.3553, 311.3914, 512.0000],
        [ 41.9545, 370.1071, 431.6385, 500.5055],
        [  0.0000, 391.8048, 187.7228, 512.0000],
        [501.2419, 187.9812, 511.2767, 201.9233],
        [507.1944, 195.7916, 511.5490, 216.8658],
        [173.8539, 460.3328, 448.6479, 506.3229],
        [  0.0000, 200.4993, 224.5978, 455.6439],
        [432.5095, 107.3605, 448.2870, 123.3097],
        [  0.0000, 484.3896, 181.2187, 512.0000],
        [252.8410, 352.4666, 269.2491, 364.2188],
        [141.6757, 485.4147, 439.0354, 512.0000],
        [252.6323, 341.7145, 267.7503, 353.9413],
        [134.9624, 314.2813, 474.5851, 492.6868],
        [505.2639, 237.3413, 511.8117, 262.1838],
        [  0.0000, 297.2654, 370.9958, 492.1260],
        [506.8980, 181.4306, 511.8102, 204.6986],
        [171.3477, 413.2979, 487.6665, 512.0000],
        [507.0528, 298.5904, 511.8441, 309.8073],
        [336.4479, 267.7834, 499.2108, 496.2349],
        [178.1360, 341.3546, 367.1203, 504.6978],
        [244.6255, 218.8507, 257.6999, 231.4108],
        [504.0644, 254.3425, 511.8181, 268.0185],
        [  0.0000, 365.2629,  39.0588, 512.0000],
        [258.7524, 340.9509, 271.9611, 353.5555],
        [507.1984, 443.6097, 511.7004, 455.8767],
        [346.1955, 170.9065, 358.2302, 184.1580],
        [ 50.2086, 324.4587, 251.0680, 512.0000],
        [198.5728, 322.8210, 209.8158, 330.6772],
        [498.2428, 141.8683, 511.1887, 224.0274],
        [297.8328, 483.9214, 500.6504, 512.0000],
        [383.7580, 302.3506, 406.5758, 328.4388],
        [190.7700, 319.5901, 203.9809, 330.4897],
        [248.1737, 341.2397, 272.0346, 364.2649],
        [ 41.9480, 182.3307, 309.7350, 511.4400],
        [507.6814, 465.5771, 511.6959, 478.4059],
        [  0.0000, 414.7599,  16.6887, 512.0000],
        [  0.0000, 495.9020,   9.1763, 512.0000],
        [506.0956, 484.8349, 511.6204, 508.3524],
        [  0.0000, 484.2805,  14.1195, 512.0000],
        [186.2599, 231.2097, 451.8763, 466.7952],
        [465.1697, 499.5819, 508.8633, 512.0000],
        [359.1404, 416.1848, 416.8053, 512.0000],
        [444.5928, 200.7507, 457.7525, 216.0354],
        [348.6382, 146.4818, 362.1615, 155.7809],
        [288.0855, 181.4522, 306.9987, 202.8014],
        [138.3017, 199.5426, 152.1866, 214.0261],
        [ 54.3134, 322.8700,  66.6056, 339.6511],
        [236.9178, 176.1253, 256.1872, 195.2987],
        [183.0305, 224.6637, 198.1654, 238.4647],
        [255.3874, 337.9686, 452.8956, 505.8088],
        [195.6607, 342.5625, 207.6055, 351.6043],
        [478.7965, 262.2610, 510.4778, 512.0000],
        [507.0534,  62.8041, 511.7828,  83.3675],
        [506.9258, 247.0326, 511.7821, 269.0636],
        [  0.0000, 482.6279,  39.7247, 512.0000],
        [  0.0000, 400.6234,  62.0636, 497.9158],
        [504.7887, 295.1768, 511.6837, 314.4619],
        [503.7539, 444.5576, 511.6874, 469.6237],
        [420.8303, 139.0130, 435.5850, 155.6219],
        [  0.0000, 169.4536,  35.6173, 512.0000],
        [505.5238, 216.9875, 511.8623, 244.7741],
        [493.3357, 183.2157, 510.4757, 225.7995],
        [283.5856, 184.4567, 294.6422, 199.1284],
        [506.1086, 172.9610, 511.7372, 195.6782],
        [421.7606, 478.9979, 506.9432, 512.0000],
        [  0.0000, 128.1171, 182.0242, 372.1508],
        [266.6456, 212.4419, 285.0941, 230.3711],
        [242.4399, 337.2843, 292.0536, 369.6913],
        [490.5333, 151.4534, 511.3717, 199.9196],
        [195.0700, 317.0647, 208.6026, 328.3253],
        [506.5237, 166.3083, 511.7383, 186.4610],
        [285.0119, 210.5486, 302.8143, 227.0892],
        [507.7259, 159.7037, 511.7627, 177.6721],
        [507.2086, 409.5898, 511.7660, 443.1966],
        [486.4733,   1.5067, 511.0473,  32.8377],
        [499.7045, 410.5609, 511.2081, 495.3992],
        [381.5405, 282.1667, 394.4013, 292.7220],
        [398.5074,  97.8511, 408.5006, 109.4040],
        [286.4212,  66.7245, 305.3555,  84.7535],
        [ 53.2904, 198.9514,  72.6522, 218.6958],
        [  0.0000, 119.1250, 352.9160, 404.2254],
        [305.2835, 262.8656, 322.0334, 282.8750],
        [ 67.7342, 107.0263,  79.3835, 116.1997],
        [504.5052, 328.6933, 511.7248, 354.2790],
        [505.5066, 454.7970, 511.6003, 479.1691],
        [297.2463, 179.5240, 459.4996, 500.3919],
        [505.9551, 116.8015, 511.8934, 139.2066],
        [ 51.7288, 143.0008,  70.2031, 162.0272],
        [281.4141, 178.7466, 292.6686, 195.8384],
        [329.5997, 233.1259, 344.1964, 247.8056],
        [308.4427, 105.4068, 324.9741, 120.8449],
        [173.9055, 208.1558, 187.9732, 223.4990],
        [506.5709, 396.8288, 511.6976, 427.8991],
        [281.4510, 187.4271, 317.5686, 229.1852],
        [395.2721, 351.2404, 407.8893, 365.8526],
        [501.4947, 463.5199, 511.3037, 476.1774]]), 'labels': tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1]), 'scores': tensor([0.7932, 0.7808, 0.7726, 0.7688, 0.7644, 0.7624, 0.7563, 0.7557, 0.7481,
        0.7428, 0.7417, 0.7415, 0.7414, 0.7403, 0.7378, 0.7354, 0.7293, 0.7268,
        0.7256, 0.7235, 0.7196, 0.7195, 0.7192, 0.7175, 0.7163, 0.7160, 0.7130,
        0.7126, 0.7122, 0.7120, 0.7120, 0.7095, 0.7095, 0.7094, 0.7083, 0.7065,
        0.7048, 0.7042, 0.7041, 0.7038, 0.7006, 0.7005, 0.6998, 0.6997, 0.6974,
        0.6974, 0.6969, 0.6963, 0.6958, 0.6950, 0.6949, 0.6946, 0.6946, 0.6936,
        0.6925, 0.6915, 0.6897, 0.6897, 0.6884, 0.6880, 0.6862, 0.6861, 0.6858,
        0.6855, 0.6853, 0.6848, 0.6844, 0.6836, 0.6827, 0.6823, 0.6814, 0.6808,
        0.6797, 0.6784, 0.6770, 0.6769, 0.6766, 0.6764, 0.6764, 0.6755, 0.6754,
        0.6735, 0.6733, 0.6720, 0.6715, 0.6713, 0.6712, 0.6697, 0.6693, 0.6687,
        0.6673, 0.6671, 0.6670, 0.6669, 0.6663, 0.6658, 0.6658, 0.6658, 0.6657,
        0.6654])}]
```

Where losses are not calculated as shown by the first dictionary

Comment: ok now we're getting somewhere! can you add `print(detections, detector_losses)` to `eval_forward` and see what it says?

Comment: I've fixed my errors, see my amended code above

Answer (score 0):

By following the code provided by @jhso I determine validation loss by looking at the losses dictionary, sum all of these losses, and at the end average them by the length of the dataloader:

```
def evaluate_loss(model, data_loader, device):
    val_loss = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
      for images, targets in data_loader:
          images = list(image.to(device) for image in images)
          targets = [{k: v.to(device) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]
          losses_dict, detections = eval_forward(model, images, targets)
         
          losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())

          val_loss += losses
          
    validation_loss = val_loss/ len(data_loader)    
    return validation_loss
```

I then place it into the following loop for training and evaluation:

```
import utils
from engine import train_one_epoch, evaluate


for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # train for one epoch, printing every 10 iterations
        train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, train_data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
        # update the learning rate
        lr_scheduler.step()
        # new function that determines validation loss
        validation_loss  = evaluate_loss(model, valid_data_loader, device=device)
        print(validation_loss)

        # evaluate on the test dataset
        evaluate(model, valid_data_loader, device=device)
```

I think this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In Pytorch, The model configured in different mode , when the model is in training mode it return the training loss only and during the evaluation mode it return the prediction->boxes, score, labels.

```
@torch.jit.unused
def eager_outputs(self, losses, detections):
    # type: (Dict[str, Tensor], List[Dict[str, Tensor]]) -> Union[Dict[str, Tensor], List[Dict[str, Tensor]]]
    if self.training:
        return losses

    return detections
```

so there are two options to get the loss for the validation loss, either execute the training in script mode or do the modification in the code( easy and long process ) , while returning detection only we can also pass the computed loss for validation to return like this in below file path ->
**vision/torchvision/models/detection/generalized_rcnn.py**

```
@torch.jit.unused
def eager_outputs(self, losses, detections):
    # type: (Dict[str, Tensor], List[Dict[str, Tensor]]) -> Union[Dict[str, Tensor], List[Dict[str, Tensor]]]
    if self.training:
        return losses

    return losses,detections
```

In most of the pytorch code , they did the same like retinanet , fasterrcnn.